# jQuery: UTF-8 not working with ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, utf-8, character

I have a php file which uses `jQuery.ajax()` to grab some data from another php file into a div.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    encoding:"UTF-8",
    dataType:"html", 
    contentType: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
    url: '/path/data.php',
    success: function(msg) {
        jQuery('#dataBox').html(msg);
    }
});
```

My problem is that if I have some "special" characters in the data I'm getting through ajax such as åäö then I get the "question mark in a black diamond"-mark. If I open the external file in the browser it works. If I put some special characters on the main page, it works.

Some simplified code:

data.php:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "pass", "db");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00'");
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sometext) AS mytext FROM `mytable`");
$stmt -> execute();
$results = selectResults($stmt);
$stmt -> close();
$mysqli -> close();
```

selectResults function:

```
function selectResults($stmt)
{
    $parameters = array();
    $results = array();

    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while ( $field = $meta->fetch_field() ) {   
     $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
      $x = array();
      foreach( $row as $key => $val ) {
         $x[$key] = $val;
      }
      $results[] = $x;
    }

    return $results;

}
```

data.php:

```
foreach($results as $result){
 $textArray = explode(',', $result['mytext']);
}
foreach($textArray as $text){
echo($text);
}
```

Comment: Is your PHP script saved as UTF8 file?

Comment: You probably need to utf8_encode the content that the ajax call is getting back. I've been able to solve the same problem myself with å,ä,ö.

Comment: Check your PHP encoding. Are you sure it's UTF-8? What you describe are classic symptoms of mismatching encodings.

Comment: @roasted Yes the PHP script is saved as a UTF-8 file.

Comment: @Alex How and where should I do that?

Comment: @geedubb Where do I check that?

Comment: What happend if you go to /path/data.php in your browser ?

Comment: @Stéphane It works as expected

Comment: That should be in your data.php where you output the data. That is because ajax expect the content to be UTF-8 since you set it as a property of the call( encoding:"UTF-8" ).

Comment: @Alex That did it! I put `utf8_encode()` around the data I was printing.

Comment: You don't need `utf8_encode`, that's a band-aid solution and will sooner or later cause bugs because it will happily "double encode" strings already in utf-8. PHP is perfectly fine with UTF-8 encoded strings as is. `utf8_encode` helps only if the underlying data is in ISO-8859-1, in which case you should simply change what encoding the underlying data is, not use `utf8_encode`

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but if you get the unicode replacement character �, then the input has been interpreted in UTF-8 but the raw bytes of the input did not match UTF-8, I.E. it was not UTF-8.

If you see the correct characters when visiting the page directly, then it must be those ajax parameters forcing UTF-8 interpretation on data that is actually in some other encoding, the default is Windows-1252 for browsers.

Post the php code and/or the raw bytes of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by setting `utf8_encode()` around the data that I `echo()` in the data.php file. Didn't think of trying this since it worked fine when opening data.php in the browser.

EDIT:

Moved the `utf8_encode()` to the selectResults function instead so that it encodes all values that I get from the database.

Comment: Please read this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198907/jquery-utf-8-not-working-with-ajax-request/14199064#comment19685818_14198907

Comment: @Esailija So what should I do instead?

Comment: Show the code, your data is not in UTF-8. It's in ISO-8859-1, which is why `utf8_encode` worked. You want your data to be UTF-8 to begin with, so you don't need `utf8_encode` every time.

Comment: All I do is connecting to my database using mysqli. Then I get the results through a select statement and put the results in an array. I do the exact same thing all over the website but it is just when using ajax that it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to do `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` before doing any queries. This will make all query results to be in utf-8 when you receive them. Trust me, you don't want to think about when to use `utf8_encode` and when not... you want everything to be utf-8 always.

Comment: Are you using any functions on the data? Please just show your code :)

Comment: Well the only way you would get replacement characters now is if you used some functions or array access on the strings, but that's not in your code so maybe the old result was cached or something.

Comment: @Esailija Is setting a `utf8_encode()` as I did in the updated answer a bad thing in someway?

Comment: Well I am not familiar with a case where `set_charset("utf8")` would still make the DB give you ISO-8859-1, but in a case where it starts working, you will have problems.

Comment: `utf8_encode` converts from the encoding ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 (It should be named `iso88591_to_utf8`). If the string is not in ISO-8859-1, it will mutilate it. It is only working because the DB is giving you ISO-8859-1, even though it should give you UTF-8.

Comment: Just found my first problem. It now changes ö to Ã¶ where it worked before. The main page that is. Though it works on fine on the data loaded through ajax.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22333/discussion-between-esailija-and-oskwish)

Answer (score 1):

I'll write this as an answer since it might help others more easily.

To solve the problem you must see to it that the content you are outputting is the same as ajax expects it to be so for utf-8  the content need to be utf-8 or encoded as utf-8 using

```
utf8_encode($content);
```

If you could provide utf-8 content from the database as Esailija says you would not need to use the encode-function.